# Como fazer a tag IMG exibir a imagem com as dimensões reais e com responsividade?

Tags: css

Tenho uma lista dinâmica em `php` de guia comercial em que há banners com diversas dimensões, só que todos estão sendo esticados ao máximo. Como fazer os banners serem listados cada qual em seu tamanho real e com responsividade?

Veja na imagem o que está acontecendo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As dimensões da imagem acima estão sendo levadas ao limite máximo do tamanho da `section`, mas preciso que cada imagem fique com suas reais dimensões.

```
<section class="guialistar">
<article>
<h2>TITULO</h2>
<figure>
<img src="./propaganda_guiacomercial/banner/falqueto.jpg">
</figure>
</article>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.guialistar{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.guialistar h2 {
  font-size: 20;
  background-color: #E2EDF5;
  color: #0E69A9;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.guialistar img{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 885px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: você está definindo na tag img que a width é 100%, isso faz com que a imagem tenha sempre a largura total da div pai, no caso a guialistar

Comment: @BrunoCastro Mas qual valor devo definir para que os banners tenham tamanho real e com  resposividade?

Comment: Tamanho real seria o tamanho original da imagem? se for isso vc não precisa definir width nenhum! A imagem será carregada do tamanho original

Comment: @BrunoCastro Fiz o solicitado e não funcionou, continua do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Faça desse jeito. .guialistar img{
  float: left;
}, lembre-se de atualizar o navegador com ctrl+f5 para limpar o cachê do navegador. Caso não funcione volte aqui que vamos tentar resolver de outra forma :)

Comment: @BrunoCastro Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado.

Comment: Que Bom! Vou transformar em resposta ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça desse jeito.

```
.guialistar img{ 
  float: left; 
}
```

Quando não definimos nenhuma `width` para a tag `img` a imagem é carregada e exibida em suas dimensões originais.

*lembre-se de atualizar o navegador com ctrl+f5 para limpar o cachê do navegador.*